# how to activate only one of the three buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made three buttons using 'map'.
It also specified a function to change the false value to true when clicked.

However, if you press one button, all three buttons are activated.
How can I activate just one button?

false = #fff
true = blue

```
const [funnalBtn, setFunnalBtn] = useState(false);
const hadleChangeBtnColor = () => {
setFunnalBtn(prev => !prev);
};

<FunnalTarget>
    {FUNNAL_DATA.map(data => {
      return (
        <FunnalButton
          key={data.id}
          text={data.text}
          hadleChangeBtnColor={hadleChangeBtnColor}
          funnalBtn={funnalBtn}
        />
      );
    })}
  </FunnalTarget>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOMZm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe8h4.png)

Comment: Instead of a boolean for your state, how about a number which is the index of the active button?

Comment: ... or an extra key in FUNNAL_DATA to indicate wether the button is activated or not.

Comment: I would like to express my gratitude to everyone. I worked with the index number of the active button, but it worked as I wanted.

Comment: How about rendering each `FunnalButton` component as (equally named) radio control (all together a radio group). Thus one gets this behavior provided  for free? Styling it to ones (or to the users) needs is a pure CSS based task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a `selectedBtn` state and pass the id of the selected target to it:

```
const [selectedBtn, setSelectedBtn] = useState(-1);

const hadleChangeBtnColor = (id) => {
    setSelectedBtn(id);
};

<FunnalTarget>
    {FUNNAL_DATA.map(data => {
      return (
        <FunnalButton
          key={data.id}
          text={data.text}
          hadleChangeBtnColor={() => setSelectedBtn(data.id)}
          funnalBtn={selectedBtn === data.id}
        />
      );
    })}
  </FunnalTarget>
```

Comment: It was hard to apply the map function.
Thank you. Thanks to you, I solved the problem.